# Conditional CASE statement syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I need help writing a case statement for a view.  The base table has 2 columns that I'll be referencing: 'Stage' and 'YesNo'.

If Stage column is 1, and the YesNo column is 1, I need the CASE statement to show it in the view as 'No.'  If the Stage column is 1, and the YesNo column is 0, I need the CASE statement to show it in the view as 'Yes.'  If the Stage column is 1, and the YesNo column is NULL, I need the CASE statement to show it in the view as NULL.  If the Stage is anything other than 1, I need the YesNo column to show in the view as NULL.

This is my logic so far which I think is correct, but when I try to run it, I get a syntax error about the word 'AS'. Any suggestions?

```
CASE 
    WHEN a.Stage = 1 and a.YesorNo = 1 THEN 'No' 
    ELSE WHEN a.Stage = 1 and a.YesorNo = 0 THEN 'Yes' 
END AS NewViewColumn
```

Comment: Can I just say that having a column called 'YesOrNo' where 1 means 'No' makes me cry a little bit inside.

Comment: I strongly suggest you take note of Matt's comment and fix your naming/data scheme. First, in programming it is (almost?) universally true that 1 means True and 0 means False. Reversing this is extremely strange and makes your code significantly harder to read and understand. Second, although you haven't mentioned your table name `YesOrNo` is not a very good column name because it's an answer to a question, not an attribute. A better name would be `IsDeleted` or `NeedsExpressHandling` or `HasPermission` or something that is obviously True/False.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `ELSE WHEN`, if you leave the `ELSE` out then it will return `null` for any items not meeting the remaining logic:

```
CASE 
    WHEN a.Stage = 1 and a.YesorNo = 1 THEN 'No' 
    WHEN a.Stage = 1 and a.YesorNo = 0 THEN 'Yes' 
END AS NewViewColumn
```

Or use:

```
CASE 
    WHEN a.Stage = 1 and a.YesorNo = 1 THEN 'No' 
    WHEN a.Stage = 1 and a.YesorNo = 0 THEN 'Yes' 
    ELSE 'other'
END AS NewViewColumn
```

Comment: Thank you very much everyone, this quickly solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
CASE 
  WHEN a.Stage = 1 and a.YesorNo = 1 THEN 'No'   
  WHEN a.Stage = 1 and a.YesorNo = 0 THEN 'Yes'
  ELSE something else  -- If you ignored this it will be NULL
END AS NewViewColumn
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `ELSE WHEN`, this should be either `ELSE` or `WHEN .. THEN ..`:

```
CASE
  WHEN a.Stage = 1 and a.YesorNo = 1 THEN 'No'
  ELSE 'Yes'
END AS NewViewColumn
```

Or:

```
CASE
  WHEN a.Stage = 1 and a.YesorNo = 1 THEN 'No'
  WHEN a.Stage = 1 and a.YesorNo = 0 THEN 'Yes'
END AS NewViewColumn
```

Check out the [msdn page on `CASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) for more information.